RNDIS interface gets a gateway
I have a Linux device that utilizes USB gadget for RNDIS support. The goal was to be able to connect any computer this device without having to mess with IP settings. I've set a static IP address on my RNDIS device. As far as communication goes, everything works. What does not work is my host PC seems to add my RNDIS device as a gateway, thus losing internet connection. I can remote the gateway route each time I plug in my device, but this reduces the user experience.
How do I modify my RNDIS configuration in order for my host PC to not add a gateway?

The RNDIS device may have static IP address, but where and how does the host PC get the IP address settings for connecting to the RNDIS device?
If the RNDIS device provides the settings for the host, using DHCP, PPPoE or some other mechanism, then the RNDIS device should not provide a default gateway setting if it is not prepared to act as a Internet gateway.
In the terms of pppd options, that would mean removing any defaultroute options and adding nodefaultroute instead.
In generic DHCP server terms, that would mean not providing the DHCP option #3 at all - if using the ISC dhcpd for example, you should remove any option routers ... line from the dhcpd.conf file.
